# Sometimes, .splice is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am stuck with a weird error. I get .splice is not a function in the console, but in fact, I am doing .splice on a array (which is valid). Moreover, it don't get always the error. When I refresh the page, sometimes I get it and other times, I don't get it. I don't understand why. Could you explain me my mistake, what am I doing wrong here?

EDIT : I forget to mention that between my declaration of variable array (var ... = []) and my jQuery.getJSON, I am adding stuff inside my variable (integers). That is why I am using splice. I want to order well my array with my new items from the JSON. Also, all arrays contain the same amount of elements. I am always adding the same quantity of elements in each array.

Here is my problematic code :

```
 var HeightLegs = [];
 var IdLegs = [];
 var PriceLegs = [];
 var QuantityLegs = [];
 jQuery.getJSON('/products/legs.js', function (product)
 {
    for (var i = 0; i < product.variants.length; i++)
    {
        var indexToAdd = 0;
        while (indexToAdd < HeightLegs.length && HeightLegs[indexToAdd] < +(product.variants[i].option1.replace('"', '')))
        {
            indexToAdd++;
        }

        IdLegs.splice(indexToAdd, 0, product.variants[i].id);
        HeightLegs.splice(indexToAdd, 0, +(product.variants[i].option1.replace('"', '')));
        PriceLegs.splice(indexToAdd, 0, product.variants[i].price / 100);

        if (product.variants[i].inventory_policy == "continue")
            QuantityLegs.splice(indexToAdd, 0, 1);
        else {
            // MY ERROR IN THE CONSOLE IS ON THIS SPLICE ONLY!!!!
            QuantityLegs.splice(indexToAdd, 0, product.variants[i].inventory_quantity);
        }
    }
});
```

What I don't understand is that the error is not constant. Sometimes I get it and other times I won't...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I forget to mention that between my declaration of variable (beginning) and my Jquery.getJSON, I am adding stuff inside my array. That is why I am using .splice (and not .push) on this one.

Comment: Can you make an example on JSFiddle to reproduce that issue? Why are you using `getJSON` on a JavaScript file? [JavaScript is not JSON](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: You can check out my webpage that have the error if you like. Check the console and refresh a couple of times. Hopefully you'll get the error. https://decktogo.com/apps/productbuilder/stage-builder
Also, I am using getJSON to use AJAX call from Shopify and get information about my products.

Comment: I can see that var ShopifyQuantityLegs has value 1. That could be the issue. Check row 203

Comment: Oh my god... I did a little mistake and forget to replace variables while I was copy/pasting my code... Thank you bigless!!

Comment: Basically when you refresh sometimes the function gets called before the values are assigned to those arrays and hence the error.

Comment: Could you please post this as an answer instead of a comment so others can easily find this information?

Comment: @Graham I use answers when solution is broadly applicable. I use comments in situations where its mostly about debuging specific code and fixing basic mistakes. But as you wish..

Answer (score 0):

According to comments above:

Errors like `what.ever is not a function` means that `what` is defined, but method `ever` is not bound to this object. It causes only two things (if I know):

a) misspelled name of method (`ever`)

b) wrong type of object/class (`what`)

In this case, error occured because var ShopifyQuantityLegs was accidentally set to Number (ShopifyQuantityLegs=1) so b) is the clue